# How to scarpe the href using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a variable e which stores a Nokogiri::XML::Element object.

when I execute `puts e` I get on the screen the following:

```
<h3 class="fixed-recipe-card__h3">
        <a href="https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/21712/chocolate-covered-strawberries/" data-content-provider-id="" data-internal-referrer-link="hub recipe" class="fixed-recipe-card__title-link">
            <span class="fixed-recipe-card__title-link">Chocolate Covered Strawberries</span>
        </a>
    </h3>
```

I would like to scrape this part `https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/21712/chocolate-covered-strawberries/`

How can I do this using Nokogiri

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the link, you can use:

```
e.at_css("a").attributes["href"].value
```

`.at_css` returns the first element matching the CSS selector (another `Nokogiri::XML::Element`). To get a list of all matching elements, use `.css` instead.

`.attributes` gives you a hash mapping attribute name to `Nokogiri::XML::Attr`. Once you look up the desired attribute in this hash (`href`), you can call `.value` to get the actual text value.